# Como obtener valor de una fila y columna especifica de una tabla con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente tabla, necesito que al oprimir el boton "Detalles" dependiendo de en que fila se encuentre tomar el valor de la columna "Documento".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo si le doy al boton de la fila 3, guardar en una variable el valor (900.596.087-2).
Dejo el codigo de mi tabla, por si se necesita:

```
<table class="table" id="tableImport">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">[[#{table.importExcel.customerNumber}]]</th>
                                    <th scope="col">[[#{table.importExcel.customerDocument}]]</th>
                                    <th scope="col">[[#{table.importExcel.customer}]]</th>
                                    <th scope="col">[[#{table.importExcel.customerEmail}]]</th>
                                    <th scope="col">[[#{table.importExcel.customerPhone}]]</th>
                                    <th scope="col">[[#{table.importExcel.invoiceTotal}]]</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Detalles</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr th:each="debtFileTODTO:${debtFileTOsDTO}">
                                    <td th:text="${debtFileTODTO.idcustomer}" id="number"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${debtFileTODTO.iddocument}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${debtFileTODTO.customernombre}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${debtFileTODTO.customeremail}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${debtFileTODTO.customerphone}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="'$'+${#numbers.formatInteger(debtFileTODTO.invoicetotal,3,'POINT')}"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary text-white">Detalles</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: $("#detailsCustomer").click(function() {
            var customerid = document.getElementById("number").innerText;
            console.log(customerid);
             }). Use esto pero solo me toma el primer boton :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes añadir una clase a los botones de ver detalles que solo la tengan los botones como "detail-button".

luego en la seccion de scripts añades este código:

```
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("detail-button");

if(buttons && buttons.length > 0){
  for(let i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", showDetails)
  }
}


function showDetails(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const documento = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children[1].textContent;
    console.log(documento)
}
```

En la función de showDetails, se recibe el evento, mediante target averiguamos el botón que se ha pulsado, luego con parentNode seleccionamos el padre, que en primer lugar es el `div`, luego otra vez el padre, que en este caso es el `tr`. Luego con children[1] obtenemos el segundo hijo, que en este caso es el `td` correspondiente a la columna documento. luego ya solo nos hace falta coger el texto y listo